# Swift - Array filtering values in between two numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

i have a small problem.

I have an array with a integer of value:

```
let array = [99, 42, 34, 19, 167, 30, 49, 39, 75, 175, 270, 540]
```

How do I get all the values between 19 and 167 for example? There has to be a better way than a for iteration through all the integer value ? 
this is on swift. so i am looking for answer on swift.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift, you can still do this using filter

```
let array = [99, 42, 34, 19, 167, 30, 49, 39, 75, 175, 270, 540]
let newArray = array.filter{$0 > 19 && $0 < 167}
print(newArray)
```

Comment: Function that takes `n` as the parameter. In this case, `.filter()` runs through each array element and sets it as the value of `n`. The function then checks if the value of `n` passes the condition which is `greater than 19 and less than 167`. If it did not passed, the value will be removed from the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` and the pattern matching operator `~=` which is able to filter a range.

```
let array = [99, 42, 34, 19, 167, 30, 49, 39, 75, 175, 270, 540]
let range = 19...167
let filteredArray = array.filter{ range ~= $0 }
```

Consider that this operator does not filter the edges 19 and 167. The result is

```
// [99, 42, 34, 19, 167, 30, 49, 39, 75]
```

To exclude the edges write `20...168` or `20..<167`, then the result is

```
// [99, 42, 34, 30, 49, 39, 75]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filtered = array.filter { (20..<167).contains($0) }
```